# returning a grid using json data

Tags: json, express

I have the following code in my node server.  I am getting intermittent "socket not writable" issues, anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Second issue - which grid is best to display my json data?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(express.logger());
var pg = require('pg');
var async = require('async');

app.configure(function() {
  console.log("Configuring");
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

  var output = '';
  pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
    var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM links');

    query.on('row', function(row) {
      output += JSON.stringify(row);
    });

    query.on('end', function() {
      client.end();
      res.send(output);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should initialize your DB connexion at server start instead of doing it at every request response.

2 - This kind of advices is out of the stackoverflow purpose + we don't know what you want to display + we don't know what technologies / framework you use on client side (not even sure you want to output HTML...) + we don't know what data you're handling...